# First-order Peano Axioms and order-completeness of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: lo.logic, order-theory, peano-arithmetic

Definition: An ordered set is order-complete if any nonempty subset with an upper bound, has a lowest upper bound or supremo.

Notation: We denote the system of first-order Peano Axioms (along with axioms for addition and multiplication) by PA1.

1.- Can we express the order-completeness of $\mathbb{N}$ using first-order logic?
How does it look?

2.- Can we prove that natural numbers are order-complete using PA1 or it has to be considered  as an axiom?

Comment: I answered on math.stackexchange.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been answered elsewhere.